# When is the limit of a function unique?

Tags: general-topology

The limit of $f:X \to Y$ at $x$ is an element $y \in Y$ such that for any open $N$ containing $y$, there is a $V$ containing $x$ such that $f(V/\{x\})\subseteq N$.

For the particular case when $f$ is a sequence, i.e. $f: \mathbb{N}+\{\infty\} \to X$, it is well known that if $X$ is Hausdorff, then the limit is unique. This however [is not necessary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381821/not-a-hausdorff-space-although-limits-of-sequences-in-it-are-unique?rq=1). My questions are then:

1. For the case of sequences, what are necessary and sufficient conditions for $X$ so that the limit of the sequence is unique?
2. For the general case, what are necessary and sufficient conditions for $X$ and $Y$ so that the limit of the function is unique?

I'd like if these conditions are stated in terms of already well known studied conditions, e.g. separation, countability, etc; but anything is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [US](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000099) property where the limit of a sequence is unique is a quite weak separation axiom.

- As you said, Hausdorff is sufficient. A weaker sufficient condition is what was called $k_2$-Hausdorff here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4761212/86887
- $T_1$ is necessary. But basically every other separation axiom I'm aware of that is sufficient for $T_1$ is not necessary for $US$:

  - [https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=US%2B~Locally%20Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=US%2B%7ELocally%20Hausdorff)
  - [https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=US%2B~%24k_2%24-Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=US%2B%7E%24k_2%24-Hausdorff)
  - [https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=US%2B~Semi-Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=US%2B%7ESemi-Hausdorff)

If you assume spaces are first-countable, then $US$ is [equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369459/if-every-convergent-sequence-has-a-unique-limit-point-in-space-x-then-is-x) to $T_2$.

Finally, the [weakly Hausdorff](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000143) property satisfies that every continuous image of a compact Hausdorff space is closed. Then I believe such spaces have unique limits for each $f:K\to X$ with $K$ compact Hausdorff.